# QueryAsync not pulling correct data

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.forms

First I run the below line of code getting the below return: (showing image just for aid)

```
var query_user1 = await _connection.QueryAsync<FavoritesProfile>("SELECT * FROM FavoritesProfile");
```

[image]

So I clearly have FavoritesProfile in my data table loaded with values User="Shane" and Titles="The Avengers".  However, when I try the next line of code I get an Exception.

```
 var query_user = await _connection.QueryAsync<FavoritesProfile>("SELECT FROM FavoritesProfile WHERE User LIKE '%" + user + "%' AND Titles LIKE '%" + _movie.Title + "%'");
```

I made made sure that user is a string and _movie.Title is also a string.  Which also both correspond to Shane & The Avengers respectively.  I will add all the code from the class as well just in case the issue is somewhere else.  If you have any insights it would be greatly appreciated.  I know I am not implementing the SQLite database in the cleanest way.

```
    using Xamarin.Forms;
using System;
using MovieApp.Services;
using MovieApp.Models;
using SQLite;
using MovieApp.Persistance;

namespace MovieApp.Views
{
    public partial class MovieDetailsPage : ContentPage
    {
        private MovieService _movieService = new MovieService();
        private Movie _movie;
        private SQLiteAsyncConnection _connection;
        private string user = MainPage._username; //simplicity purposes as we didn't implement fully functions login page

        public class FavoritesProfile
        {
            [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
            public int Id { get; set; }

            [MaxLength(255)]
            public string User { get; set; }

            [MaxLength(255)]
            public string Titles { get; set; }
        }
        public MovieDetailsPage(Movie movie)
        {
            if (movie == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(movie));

            _movie = movie;

            InitializeComponent();

            _connection = DependencyService.Get<ISQLiteDb>().GetConnection();
        }

        protected override async void OnAppearing()
        {
            var query_user1 = await _connection.QueryAsync<FavoritesProfile>("SELECT * FROM FavoritesProfile");
            //will create table if it does not already exist
            await _connection.CreateTableAsync<FavoritesProfile>();



            //BindingContext = await _movieService.GetMovie(_movie.Title);
            BindingContext =  _movie;

            CheckForFavoriteAsync();

            base.OnAppearing();
        }

        private async void CheckForFavoriteAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                var query_user = await _connection.QueryAsync<FavoritesProfile>("SELECT FROM FavoritesProfile WHERE User LIKE '%" + user + "%' AND Titles LIKE '%" + _movie.Title + "%'");
                if (query_user.Count >= 1)
                    favoriteicon.Icon = "star_filled.png";
            } catch (Exception) {

            }
        }

        public async void Favorite_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   

            if(favoriteicon.Icon == "star_filled.png")
            {
                //unadd from favorites  for user
                try
                {
                    var query_user = await _connection.QueryAsync<FavoritesProfile>("DELETE FROM FavoritesProfile WHERE User LIKE '%" + user + "%' AND Titles LIKE '%" + _movie.Title + "%'");
                } catch (Exception)
                {

                }

                favoriteicon.Icon = "star_unfilled.png";
            } 
            else
            {
                var query_user2 = await _connection.QueryAsync<FavoritesProfile>("SELECT * FROM FavoritesProfile");
                //add to favorites for user
                try
                {
                    var query_user = await _connection.QueryAsync<FavoritesProfile>("SELECT FROM FavoritesProfile WHERE User LIKE '%" + user + "%' AND Titles LIKE '%" + _movie.Title + "%'");
                } catch (Exception)
                {
                    var favorites = new FavoritesProfile { User = user, Titles = _movie.Title };
                    await _connection.InsertAsync(favorites);
                }

                favoriteicon.Icon = "star_filled.png";
            }


        }

    }
}
```

Overall my Delete query works as well as my generic Select * queries but I cannot get the other one to filter and return to me the result that it should be.  I just want to get a result when there is already an entry with both username AND movieTitle so that I can fill in an icon to show the user they already added that movie to their favorites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You second query has an invalid SELECT statement.  You need to specify which columns you are selecting.

This line:

```
var query_user = await _connection.QueryAsync<FavoritesProfile>("SELECT FROM FavoritesProfile WHERE User LIKE '%" + user + "%' AND Titles LIKE '%" + _movie.Title + "%'");
```

Probably should be

```
var query_user = await _connection.QueryAsync<FavoritesProfile>("SELECT * FROM FavoritesProfile WHERE User LIKE '%" + user + "%' AND Titles LIKE '%" + _movie.Title + "%'");
```